# Tracking down extremely slow performance by route

Tags: magento-2.1, event-observer, performance

Using Magento 2.1.7 EE and New Relic.

I've been monitoring the performance of a site which which is almost to the point of being unusable. If I break down the transactions by most time consuming, I'm left with these three:

```
/cms/noroute/index
/customer/section/load
/search/ajax/suggest
```

Sometimes the /customer/section/load takes precedent but I'm currently focused on the first entry in that list. I did a string search for cms/noroute/index and it returned a single file: vendor/magento/module-cms/etc/config.xml

The contents of which are this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <web>
            <default>
                <cms_home_page>home</cms_home_page>
                <cms_no_route>no-route</cms_no_route>
                <cms_no_cookies>enable-cookies</cms_no_cookies>
                <front>cms</front>
                <no_route>cms/noroute/index</no_route>
                <show_cms_breadcrumbs>1</show_cms_breadcrumbs>
            </default>
        </web>
        <cms>
            <wysiwyg>
                <enabled>enabled</enabled>
            </wysiwyg>
        </cms>
        <system>
            <media_storage_configuration>
                <allowed_resources>
                    <wysiwyg_image_folder>wysiwyg</wysiwyg_image_folder>
                </allowed_resources>
            </media_storage_configuration>
        </system>
    </default>
</config>
```

I'm not seeing much from this file that would indicate bad practice or performance hogging. Is there a better way to determine if I've got an event-driven issue with Magento or some other piece of functionality which would could be globally affecting performance even on CMS pages? We've already tried restarting all services and scaling the environment 4x with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To track out such things, you need to use the built-in feature of Magento called Profiler.

Please see the [official documentation regarding profiler](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/bootstrap/mage-profiler.html).

However `cms/noroute/index` should be fast since that root is coming from core Magento. I am not saying code base of M2 is cleaner and gives the best performance. But that route is loading very fast in my M2 instance.

So you should really look into your M2 environment setup.